# Onclick Trigger functionality

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in understanding the functionality of onclick.For instance:-

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="yetAnotherAlert()" />
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yetAnotherAlert(textToAlert) {
    alert(textToAlert);
}
yetAnotherAlert("This is Chapter 2");
</script>
```

Over here I was expecting that once I click on the button,the function `yetAnotherAlert()` would be invoked.But as I open the page in my Chrome,it triggers without even clicking on the button[Onclick functionality does work here].My question is:-**Why is the function getting triggered before loading the page?**

Comment: @ProllyGeek i am new to JS and so I asked.....didn't mean to disrespect anyone....

Comment: @ProllyGeek well i do admit that it is a network for professionals, but at the same time it is also a knowledge sharing portal too.....i am not expecting any spoon feeding answers here.....plus i am not lazy to search since I was not getting a proper answer which could convince me... apology if i have disrespected you in any manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling function during page loading

```
yetAnotherAlert("This is Chapter 2");
```

Remove it. And you have to pass string during click event like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="yetAnotherAlert('This is Chapter 2')" />
```